# What is the simple way to add a left icon to each line, in an alert list dialog using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android (write in kotlin) App I have an alert dialog with a similar structure like this. The list of items is injected from a json, but for this question I made the code more simple.

```
>     var items = mutableListOf<String>()
>     items.addAll(listOf("line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line x"))
>     val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this@aplicacion)
>     var items2=items.toTypedArray()
>     with(builder)
>     {
>         setItems(items2) { dialog, i ->
>             var opcion=items[i]
>             if (opcion=="line 1") { function() }
>             //....here all the options acording list ....
>         }
>     builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->  }
>         setTitle("List of options")
>         builder.show()
>     }
```

I want want to add an image (icon) on the left of each item.
I have try a lot of solutions but nothing works.... would be the easy way to make this posible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same icon for each item, or different ones? If it’s different ones, I think you need to create a ListView or RecyclerView with an associated Adapter to use as the View of your dialog.

Comment: Diferent for each… I try with a recylclerView but It doesn’t work. Thanks for the answer